Redis random connection errors
I have a redis (single server), single pod runnning on a kubernetes cluster. I have setup TLS using openssl certificates and here is my 
Redis.conf
    cluster-enabled no
    protected-mode no
    dir /data
    port 6
    requirepass "SOMEPASSWORD"
    tls-port 6379
    tls-cert-file /tls/redis.crt
    tls-key-file /tls/redis.key
    tls-ca-cert-file /tls/ca.crt
    tls-auth-clients no

I am running a nodejs server and connecting using the redis package like this
const { Emitter } = require("@socket.io/redis-emitter");
const redis = require('redis');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const pubClient = redis.createClient({
  host: process.env.redisHost,
  port: process.env.redisPort,
  password: process.env.redisPassword,
  connectTimeout: 60 * 60 * 1000,
  tls: {
    servername: process.env.redisHost,
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    ca: [fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname,'./conf-redis/ca.crt'))]
  }
});

pubClient.on("connect", function (val) {
  console.error("ws | redis connected ",val);
});   
pubClient.on("error", function (err) {
  console.error("ws | redis error--", err);
}); 

const ioemitter = new Emitter(pubClient);

ISSUE-
I keep getting the "ws | redis error-- , ECONN reset" logs randomly, no apparent pattern. But it reconnects immediately after.
Here is these error logs i keep seeing in the redis pod logs.
1:M 27 Jul 2024 03:49:46.318 # Error accepting a client connection: error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading (conn: fd=18)
1:M 27 Jul 2024 03:49:52.631 # Error accepting a client connection: error:0A00010B:SSL routines::wrong version number
1:M 27 Jul 2024 03:49:58.096 # Error accepting a client connection: error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading
1:M 27 Jul 2024 03:49:58.319 # Error accepting a client connection: error:0A00009C:SSL routines::http request (conn: fd=18)
1:M 27 Jul 2024 03:49:58.780 # Error accepting a client connection: error:0A00010B:SSL routines::wrong version number (conn: fd=18)
1:M 27 Jul 2024 03:50:01.575 # Error accepting a client connection: error:0A00018C:SSL routines::version too low (conn: fd=18)

Could you please help me understand the problem or if something is wrongly configured, Thanks.
